# Proof of Liouville's Theorem(Conformal mappings)

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a proof of [Liouville's Theorem for conformal mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mappings%29).

I can't find any proofs online in English (I'd settle for a German proof, though I'd take forever to read it. I cannot speak or read French or Russian however).

The local library contains none of the books mentioned on the wikipedia article nor the links it provides.

Answer (score 3):

Google books seems to have an online copy of the book [Analysis and topology: a volume dedicated to the memory of S. Stoilow](http://books.google.com/books?id=O_7y33zXLJAC) which has a whole chapter, which starts on page [339](http://books.google.com/books?id=O_7y33zXLJAC&pg=PA339).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. I glanced through it(I'll have to start on it tomorrow), and conveniently it's missing the page which puts together all of the results in the chapter to prove the Liouville theorem. But it's a great start, and I may be able to find a copy in the library.